# Изменение записи

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" обновлять запись в БД, данные берутся с текстбоксов, как это можно сделать внутри команды SaveCommand во MainViewModel?

Класс MainViewModel:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SvetlanaDmitrievnaEntities dataEntities = new SvetlanaDmitrievnaEntities();
    private Service_import selectedService;
    public ObservableCollection<Service_import> Services { get; set; }

    // Команда добавления нового объекта
    private RelayCommand editCommand;
    public RelayCommand EditCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return editCommand ??
              (editCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
              {
                  Service_import service = obj as Service_import;
                  SelectedService = service;
              }));
        }
    }

    // Команда сохранения изменений
    private ICommand saveCommand;
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }

    private void Save(Service_import service)
    {
        var item = dataEntities.Service_import.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Наименование_услуги == service.Наименование_услуги);
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Наименование_услуги = service.Наименование_услуги;
            item.Длительность = service.Длительность;
            item.Стоимость = service.Стоимость;
            item.Действующая_скидка = service.Действующая_скидка;
            dataEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public ApplicationViewModel() { 
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand<Service_import>(Save); 
    }

    public Service_import SelectedService
    {
        get { return selectedService; }
        set
        {
            selectedService = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedService");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Берете объект базы данных (или модель, как я говорил вам ранее с удобными для этого органами управления в виде методов) и пишете `var item = db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == obj.Name); //имя - объект поиска, обычно используется Id. if (item != null) { item.SomeProperty = "Новое значение"; db.SaveChanges() }`. То есть при помощи LINQ `FirstOrDefault` находим сам объект из базы, меняем его и вызвав `SaveChanges()` сохраняем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А нельзя как то собрать все поля с текстбоксов в объект и просто его как то вставить в обновление? Или мне нужно по отдельности писать каждое обновляемое свойство? Допустим если 5 полей, то я должен item.SomeProperty 5 раз писать?

Comment: Забудьте про такое понятие, как текстбокс или любой другой UI элемент. У вас вроде была коллекция классов, которая привязана к UI, в UI через команду вы достаете нужных объект, вот с этим объектом и работайте, не с текстбосками, а с классом, который у вас привязан. По поводу писать 5 раз, по стандарту, если это два разных класса со своими полями, то да. Если библиотеки, такие как AutoMapper, которые позволяют за вас это все сделать, достаточно указать от куда и куда "замапить" )

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Прикрепил код, сделал как вы сказали, но он не хочет, выдает ошибку, мол "Для не являющегося статическим метода требуется указать конечный объект"

Comment: На что именно ругается?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ на переменную item

Comment: А давайте ка мы немного причешем этот класс. Сделайте простой приватный метод, который будет принимать передаваемой командой объект, например `private void Save(Service_import item) { //... }`, в него переместите всю необходимую логику по записи в базу. Свойство команды перепишите на `public ICommand SaveCommand {get;}`. Дальше я бы заменил класс [RelayCommand](https://pastebin.com/9F4Zb8TJ). Ну последнее, делаем конструктор `public ApplicationViewModel() { SaveCommand = new RelayCommand<Service_import>(Save); }`. Все, код будет чище и все по своим местам, ну и должно решить ошибку (не факт).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в приватный метод перенести логику записи в базу именно, которая с условия начинается? if(item != null)?

Comment: Ну логика записи какая, что для нее требуется? Наверно и item тоже?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вот такой код получился теперь, но он в конструкторе ApplicationViewModel подчеркивает красным RelayCommand строку

Comment: Вот, примерно [это](https://pastebin.com/YJxH1NxU) должно у вас быть. Классы по нужным файлам раскидайте только.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сделал, но ошибка всё равно осталась, прикрепил выше скриншот

Comment: А вы правильно то EF используете? Посмотрите [пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.2.php) и посмотрите как у вас. Предположу, что у вас неверно реализован EF и `dataEntities.Service_import` отдает вам не то, что надо. И тут я вам уже не помощник, ибо сам мало работал с EF.